# How I return the value of jcombobox when I push a jbutton

Tags: java

I'm new of Java and I want to know how I print a value selected from a `JComboBox` when I push a `JButton`. This is a part of my code:

```
public class inizio extends javax.swing.JFrame {


public inizio() {
    initComponents();
}


private void initComponents() {

    jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4" }));
    jComboBox1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jComboBox1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton1.setText("jButton1");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(27, 27, 27)
            .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(169, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addGap(152, 152, 152))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(117, 117, 117)
            .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(52, 52, 52)
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addContainerGap(84, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jComboBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           


}                                          

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

}
```

In `private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)` how I take the value of `JComboBox` from `evt`? Thank you!

Comment: Just a tip: with `import javax.swing.JComboBox` you can write `jComboBox1 = new JComboBox();`. Likewise for other classes, and asterix also works, e.g., `import javax.swing.*` for all Swing classes.
According convention classes are capitalised, i.e. `Inizio`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jComboBox1.getSelectedItem()
```

gives you the item. Test it like this:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(jComboBox1.getSelectedItem()));
}
```

And `jComboBox1` should be a member field, set by your constructor, in order for `jButton1ActionPerformed()` to use it:

```
class inizio {
    JComboBox jComboBox1;

    inizio() {
        jComboBox1 = new JComboBox();
        initComponents();
    }
}
```

You can read more info about the method [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#getSelectedItem%28%29).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot take the value of `jComboBox` from `evt`.
You can use `jComboBox1.getSelectedItem()` to get the selected item since your `jComboBox1` seems to be a field which should be accessible from inside the method.
P.S: If you are not already doing so, you should start using an IDE like eclipse.